# Google login in Ionic 4 getting error code 10

Tags: cordova, ionic4

I want login using google account in cordova app for android platform by using cordova googleplus plugin. So I have made an android app on console developers google on google account and integrate it with my cordova app but when I tried to run my cordova app on emulator I am facing error with code:10 and when I run on android phone the error becomes error:10.

Comment: Does the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same error. But I some how fixed it. Let me explain the steps for Ionic 4 Google Login

**Step 1**

Open your config.xml file and edit your `widget id` into  a new one. Usually it will be `io.ionic.project` , you can change it into any name as per your wish

**Step 2**

Open your  Firebase Console , add a new Project . Inside the Project add platform for both Android and Ios. In the App ID field, provide your `widget id` . Once you finish the Ios setting a file will be ready to download(**GoogleService-Info.plist** file)

**Step 3**

Open the file  and copy REVERSED_CLIENT_ID

**Step 4**

Open CMD and run below command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_REVERSE_CLIENT_ID
```

This one also

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus@beta
```

**Step 5**

Now add Google Auth to your Ionic 4 App

Open your page.component.ts

```
 import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

constructor(private googlePlus: GooglePlus) { }

...

this.googlePlus.login({})
  .then(res => console.log(res)
        console.log('Response from Google',res);
        )

  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting what worked for me when I encountered the same problem.
I had an already configured app that I was trying to debug on my local machine. When I attempted a Google login, I got the `error "10"`.
In my case, **I was missing the signing key for debug environment** (the signing key that is not used for releasing the app to the play store, rather just to register your locally deployed app for testing purposes. More info on creating that key over here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

In short, you create an SHA-1 key using a tool that is already bundled with java called "keytool".

After creating that key, you need to head over to the Firebase console, then "settings". You should see your apps there and the button to download your `google-services.json` file.

You can click on "Add fingerprint" near the bottom of the "Your apps" section. Right there you paste your previously generated key. Now you can download the new google-services.json file, which includes the definition of a new type 1 client (android client) inside the oauth_client array, along with it's signing key which is the one you created for yourself.

In the image below you can see three Sha certificates, which probably means that three developers were testing the app locally and needed their own SHA keys uploaded to firebase.

Your apps setting menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was very cryptic.

Cordova was using the default keystore from %USERPROFILE%./.android/debug.keystore which is diferent that what i had set in Firebase, hence the Google signin service was failling.

To get the solution I just ran
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
password: android

Copied the SHA-1 from this and updated it in my Firebase project SHA-1 and oAuth2 API SHA-1.

That's it. It started working.

Check this [github link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/243#issuecomment-245908012) for details.